# Why does my migration cause "NoMethodError: undefined method `jsonb' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, repository

I am getting a lot of issues, since midway through its installation, the migration files stop working and the remaining 2 won't migrate due to a jsonb issue. However, this repository works completely fine if I install it as a gem.

Repository - https://github.com/SpinaCMS/Spina

Versions:

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin17]
Rails 5.1.6
rvm 1.29.3 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
```

Running the installation locally:

```
MacBook-Pro:tgs Work$ rails g spina:install
Running via Spring preloader in process 15218
      create  config/initializers/spina.rb
      create  config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
      create  config/initializers/mobility.rb
       route  mount Spina::Engine => '/'
        rake  spina:install:migrations
Copied migration 20180403040054_create_spina_tables.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040055_create_spina_translation_tables.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040056_create_spina_navigations.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040057_add_password_reset_token_to_spina_users.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040058_remove_translated_columns.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040059_create_spina_options.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040060_create_spina_settings.spina.rb from spina
Copied migration 20180403040061_create_spina_media_folders.spina.rb from spina
        rake  db:migrate
== 20180403040054 CreateSpinaTables: migrating ================================
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_accounts", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0265s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_attachment_collections", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0182s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_attachment_collections_attachments", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0117s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_attachments", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0142s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_layout_parts", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0132s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_lines", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0147s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_page_parts", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0148s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_pages", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0158s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_photo_collections", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0110s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_photo_collections_photos", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0130s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_photos", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0120s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_structure_items", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0142s
-- add_index("spina_structure_items", ["structure_id"], {:name=>"index_spina_structure_items_on_structure_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0117s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_structure_parts", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0144s
-- add_index("spina_structure_parts", ["structure_item_id"], {:name=>"index_spina_structure_parts_on_structure_item_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0129s
-- add_index("spina_structure_parts", ["structure_partable_id"], {:name=>"index_spina_structure_parts_on_structure_partable_id", :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0149s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_structures", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0142s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_texts", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0148s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_users", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0118s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_rewrite_rules", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0143s
== 20180403040054 CreateSpinaTables: migrated (0.2917s) =======================

== 20180403040055 CreateSpinaTranslationTables: migrating =====================
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_page_translations", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0138s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_line_translations", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0168s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_text_translations", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0160s
== 20180403040055 CreateSpinaTranslationTables: migrated (0.0474s) ============

== 20180403040056 CreateSpinaNavigations: migrating ===========================
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_navigations", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0148s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table("spina_navigation_items", {:force=>:cascade, :id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0120s
== 20180403040056 CreateSpinaNavigations: migrated (0.0271s) ==================

== 20180403040057 AddPasswordResetTokenToSpinaUsers: migrating ================
-- add_column(:spina_users, :password_reset_token, :string)
   -> 0.0162s
-- add_column(:spina_users, :password_reset_sent_at, :datetime)
   -> 0.0137s
== 20180403040057 AddPasswordResetTokenToSpinaUsers: migrated (0.0301s) =======

== 20180403040058 RemoveTranslatedColumns: migrating ==========================
-- remove_column(:spina_lines, :content)
   -> 0.0153s
-- remove_column(:spina_texts, :content)
   -> 0.0143s
-- remove_column(:spina_pages, :title)
   -> 0.0161s
-- remove_column(:spina_pages, :menu_title)
   -> 0.0125s
-- remove_column(:spina_pages, :description)
   -> 0.0179s
-- remove_column(:spina_pages, :seo_title)
   -> 0.0140s
-- remove_column(:spina_pages, :materialized_path)
   -> 0.0182s
== 20180403040058 RemoveTranslatedColumns: migrated (0.1087s) =================

== 20180403040059 CreateSpinaOptions: migrating ===============================
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table(:spina_options, {:id=>:integer})
   -> 0.0130s
== 20180403040059 CreateSpinaOptions: migrated (0.0134s) ======================

== 20180403040060 CreateSpinaSettings: migrating ==============================
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- adapter_name()
   -> 0.0000s
-- create_table(:spina_settings, {:id=>:integer})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `jsonb' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition:0x007fb0f1c4a2d0>
Did you mean?  json
/Users/work/Documents/Working/tgs/db/migrate/20180403040060_create_spina_settings.spina.rb:6:in `block in change'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:46:in `block in create_table'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:282:in `create_table'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:363:in `create_table'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `say_with_time'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:838:in `method_missing'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:45:in `create_table'
/Users/work/Documents/Working/tgs/db/migrate/20180403040060_create_spina_settings.spina.rb:4:in `change'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:792:in `exec_migration'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:776:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:408:in `with_connection'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:774:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1230:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1300:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1201:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `each'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1148:in `block in migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1317:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1148:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

Caused by:
NoMethodError: undefined method `jsonb' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition:0x007fb0f1c4a2d0>
Did you mean?  json
/Users/work/Documents/Working/tgs/db/migrate/20180403040060_create_spina_settings.spina.rb:6:in `block in change'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:46:in `block in create_table'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:282:in `create_table'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:363:in `create_table'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `say_with_time'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:838:in `method_missing'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration/compatibility.rb:45:in `create_table'
/Users/work/Documents/Working/tgs/db/migrate/20180403040060_create_spina_settings.spina.rb:4:in `change'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:792:in `exec_migration'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:776:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:408:in `with_connection'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:774:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1230:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1300:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1201:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `each'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1148:in `block in migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1317:in `with_advisory_lock'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1148:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/work/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: What do you mean by a `JSON issue`, always try to give as much information as possible, stacktrace, logs, ruby versions, gem versions, os... so it'd be easier for someone to understand and help you.

Comment: My sincere apologies - please see my amended post.

Comment: The error mentions "*undefined method \`jsonb' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition:0x007fb0f1c4a2d0> Did you mean?  json*" `jsonb` is only supported on PostreSQL

Comment: Pro tip: questions should be phrased to ask what the problem is, not "please help me and do my work". Aside from asking too much of volunteers, that's not a approach that is compatible with readable, technical writing. Remember that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to create questions that are useful for future readers, not just for question authors. Of course, you should give enough information so that if helpers _wish_ to fork your repo and run it for themselves, they can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do this with a `sqlite` database in your local system, and `sqlite` does not have `json` support, try changing your database to either `mysql`, `postgres` or a database system that has json support.

Comment: Do you mean when I set up my rails app? Because I am setting this up as mysql.

Comment: 'rails new appname -d mysql' is how I've set it up

Comment: as @Andrew T. points out, it only works with `postgresql` if you head over to their website at http://www.spinacms.com/guide/getting-started/prerequisites#main it lists `postgresql` as a prerequisite.

Comment: Can I ask though, how come it will work as a gem but not when it's locally?

Comment: what do you mean by "not when it's locally", for it to work a RoR app with `postgresql` db is a must,